# How to add an output column without altering the original logic in a metaprogramming script?

Tags: sql, metaprogramming, dolphindb

In the following metaprogramming script:

```
def generateReport(tbl, colNames, colFormat): sql(sqlColAlias(each(makeCall{format},sqlCol(colNames),colFormat),colNames), tbl).eval()
t = table(1..100 as id, (1..100 + 2018.01.01) as date, rand(100.0, 100) as price, rand(10000, 100) as qty, rand(`A`B`C`D`E`F`G, 100) as city);
generateReport(t, ["id", "date","price","qty"], ["0", "MM/dd/yyyy", "0.00", "#,###"]);
```

I'd like to add the "city" column as part of the query result without changing the internal logic of the `format` function. Could you please provide guidance on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1:**

You can use the `join`(<-) function. Refer to the following script:

```
def generateReport(tbl, colNames, colFormat): sql(sqlColAlias(each(makeCall{format},sqlCol(colNames),colFormat),colNames)<-sqlCol("city"), tbl).eval();
t=table(1..100 as id, (1..100 + 2018.01.01) as date, rand(100.0, 100) as price, rand(10000, 100) as qty, rand(`A`B`C`D`E`F`G, 100) as city);
generateReport(t, ["id", "date","price","qty"], ["0", "MM/dd/yyyy", "0.00", "#,###"]);
```

Output:

```
id     date     price    qty   city
1   01/02/2018  70.86   518     E
2   01/03/2018  81.32   8,132   A
3   01/04/2018  88.08   9,599   C
4   01/05/2018  77.98   4,101   G
5   01/06/2018  16.44   9,191   F
6   01/07/2018  48.81   8,953   A
7   01/08/2018  36.65   459     E
8   01/09/2018  35.80   4,012   C
……
```

**Method 2:**

For the “city” column without any specific formatting, you can define a UDF with the logic to return it unchanged. For specific details, refer to the following script:

```
def myf(colName, ft){
  if(isValid(ft)){
    return makeCall(format, sqlCol(colName), ft)
  }else{
    return sqlCol(colName)
  }
}

def generateReport(tbl, colNames, colFormat): sql(sqlColAlias(each(myf, colNames, colFormat),colNames), tbl).eval()

colNames=["id", "date","price","qty", "city"]
colFormat=["0", "MM/dd/yyyy", "0.00", "#,###", ""]
t = table(1..100 as id, (1..100 + 2018.01.01) as date, rand(100.0, 100) as price, rand(10000, 100) as qty, rand(`A`B`C`D`E`F`G, 100) as city);
generateReport(t, ["id", "date","price","qty", "city"], ["0", "MM/dd/yyyy", "0.00", "#,###", ""]);
```